# Firefox - focusing a paragraph inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, firefox

Firefox doesnt seem to set focus on paragraph inside contenteditable. I event tried to set the focus programatically. Chromes seems to do some magic and everything works fine.

```
<h2 contenteditable="true">Some text</h2><br/><br/>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p id="test">Paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

1. Click on h2 and hit tab
2. start typing - The text does not appear inside P.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/126/

```
$( "#test" ).focus(function() {
  $( "<span>Focused!</span>" ).appendTo( "body" ).fadeOut( 1000 );
});

$("#before").on('keydown', function(e){
            if(e.which == 9){
                $('#test').triggerHandler('focus');
            }

        });

$("#test").bind( "focus", function() {
   $("#test").css('background', 'yellow');   
});
```

I also tried to set the caret position but it doesnt work in firefox, works in chrome

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vXnCM/2998/

```
function setCaret() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(el, 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem only occurs when you press tab, not when you manually click on it, right?

Comment: did you want it so that it selects all of the text inside? or set the caret to the end of the pre-filled text?

Comment: Its only a problem with tab. I just want to start typing in paragraph as soon as i hit tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't have any official Firefox info, but when I merged your two jsfiddle examples together, I was able to get the caret in the right place.  This seems to work well for me in Firefox 30 on Mac OSX 1.9.4.  I was able to recreate the exact original problem by simply commenting out the call to `setCaret()`.

[Merged JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/151/)

One thing I changed while merging the code was to move the element focus to happen before all of the range manipulation, but I'm not certain that has any impact.

Comment: You probably need to do some browser detection though: hitting tab in IE and Chrome for some reason will focus the address bar with this code

Comment: @kapep Interesting!  I wasn't even thinking cross-browser when merging the original examples.  YMMV, I guess.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work when you have two paragraphs. Hit tab and start typing then hit enter you ll have new paragraph. Now go to h2 element and hit tab again, it doesnt seem to focus.

Comment: Well, now you're changing the scenario.

Comment: Tested in Chrome, FireFox, and IE11.  Works great with single and multiple paragraphs and tabbing focuses fine. Going back to h2 and hitting tab, goes back to the start.  

Maybe you should look into tabbing to the end of the block of HTML? Or not worry about tabbing to other places, as users will tab, see the caret and then move to where they want to edit anyway.

Comment: @TLS Thank you so much for this. The `setCaret` gave me a whole new dimension for the kind of problem i am solving in my editor. :)